# jquery hover not showing link

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not understanding why my link won't show up when I hover over an image. I'm sure it is something very simple that I am unable to see at this time. I would be very appreciative if someone pointed out what I'm missing as well as any other tips one may have.

```
$("#profile_pic").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).show($('<a id="duh" href="upload.php">Change the picture</a>'));
        }
);
```

The link I'm trying to get to show on hover is below

```
<div>
    <img id= "profile_pic" src="<?php echo $picture;?>" width="164" height="164" />
</div>
```

Comment: You could just move the `id="profilepic"` onto the wrapper div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the issue is that `<img>` elements can't have content, yet you're trying to append that markup to it.

What you could do is append that to the parent.

```
$("#profile_pic").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).closest('div').append($('<a id="duh" href="upload.php">Change the picture</a>'));
        });
```

Now, however you do this, note that the `.hover()` API will result in your function being called each time that the mouse moves in or out of the element.  Each call will append *another* block of HTML. Do you really want to do that?

I suggest that, instead, you *always* have that `<a>` tag on the page, and that you make your `.hover()` handler show/hide it.

Comment: Ok thanks, did not know the consequences of not using the <a>.

Answer (score 1):

You can't append anything to img, but you can insert link next to your img.

```
$("#profile_pic").hover(
   function () {
    var link = $("#duh");
    link = link.length ? link : $('<a id="duh" href="upload.php">Change the picture</a>');
    $(this).after(link);
   });
```

Comment: I wonder if the link would be clickable if the hover moves off the image - the link would be removed...

Comment: I voice the same concerns as how can I then click on the link?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: You are right it might be a problem... I've removed this part.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just move the id onto the wrapper div? Or give the wrapper it's own class or id?

```
<div id="profile_pic">
    <img src="<?php echo $picture;?>" width="164" height="164" />
</div>​
```

.

```
$("#profile_pic").hover(
    function () {
    $(this).append($('<a id="duh" href="upload.php">Change the picture</a>'));
 });​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#profile_pic").hover(
            function () {
                $(this).after($('<a id="duh" href="upload.php">Change the picture</a>'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#profile_pic").hover(function () {
    $('<a id="duh" href="upload.php">Change the picture</a>').insertAfter(this);
});
```

I used the insertAfter as I do not have knowlege of your other structure, and appending to the parent/wrapper might not put it in close proximity to the image whereas this should.  You could also use the `$(this).parent()` selector to append if needed.